# How can IndexError: tuple index out of range appear on one computer but not on another?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to compare `data_x` with `data_y`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mplcol

data_x = [np.random.rand(1,), np.random.rand(1,)]
data_y = [np.random.rand(9,), np.random.rand(11,)]
data_z = [np.random.rand(9,), np.random.rand(11,)]

cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('viridis')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for x, y, z in zip(data_x, data_y, data_z):
    for y2, z2 in zip(y, z):
        sc = ax.scatter(x, y2, c=z2, cmap=cm, norm=mplcol.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1))
cb = plt.colorbar(sc)
plt.show()
```

When I run it on my computer with Python 3.7 `IndexError: tuple index out of range` appears but when I run it on another computer with Python 3.6.6 it executes without any errors.

Can anyone explain to me why? How can I make it work on my computer?

Comment: can you be more specific about what you try to compare

Comment: Thank you for showing interest, @Shubham Shaswat. `data_x` are data at a specific frequency while `data_y` are data at various frequencies (`data_z`). I want to check the frequency-dependent. The data above is obviously not my dataset but examples of data with the same structure.

Answer (score 0):

The input parameters `y` and `c` to `scatter` should be iterable, while you are feeding float numbers.

`sc = ax.scatter(x, [y2], c=[z2], cmap=cm, norm=mplcol.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1))`